# centering absolute div using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I always use JQuery to center a div horizontally, but this time I'm doing a project without any JQuery or Javascript support.

so I want to center the div using css only and without the  tag for sure.

P.S : the div has z-index and absolute position.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using absolute positioning, use the properties "left: 50%;" and "margin-left" with a negative value equal to half the width of your div . so, for example:

```
#div {
width: (desired width);
left: 50%;
margin-left: -(half of the width of the div);
position: absolute;

}
```

The Z-index doesn't really matter to centering. If you have other elements laid on top of the div with greater Z-index values, then the div would simply be hidden underneath them.

Comment: I found another solution by making a container div for my div but relative & centered, but your solution is less redundant. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah no prob, I suggested this way because you specified you were using absolute positioning. Another way which I prefer is to simply set a containers "margin-left" and "margin-right" both to "auto". For example:
#div {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
} 

that should be good.

Also, don't forget to select a best answer by click the arrow sign next to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CRhbF/

This will work only if you know the dimensions of the absolutely positioned, centered, element.